# Is there Performance related difference in using aggregate function in ORDER BY clause and alias of aggregate function?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, query-performance

I have a question related to `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` clause.

For example I have below queries

```
SELECT country_name,COUNT(*) FROM user_location
WHERE country_name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY country_name 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

And

```
SELECT country_name,COUNT(*) As Total FROM user_location
WHERE country_name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY country_name 
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

In 2nd query I am using alias `Total` for `COUNT(*)` in `ORDER BY` clause.

Is there any performance related differences in two queries ?

Comment: I'd expect the same execution plan on most databases.

Answer (score 1):

I've run the following test on a table with 1M products randomly related to 10K categories (MariaDB 10.0.19):

```
select p.categoryId, count(*) as total
from products p
group by p.categoryId
having count(*) = 100
```

Execution time: 156 msec

```
select p.categoryId, count(*) as total
from products p
group by p.categoryId
having total = 100
```

Execution time: 156 msec

So there doesn't seem to be any difference in performance.

Note that with `ORDER BY` the engine will copy the result into a temporary table (See EXPLAIN: `Using temporary; Using filesort`). So the value can't be recalculated, even when you use `ORDER BY COUNT(*)`.

However - There is a difference (which I can not explain) when I use `ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINGT ...)`:

```
select p.categoryId, count(distinct p.productData) as total
from products p
group by p.categoryId
order by total
```

Profile: 863 msec for `Copying to tmp table`

```
select p.categoryId, count(distinct p.productData) as total
from products p
group by p.categoryId
order by count(distinct p.productData)
```

Profile: 963 msec for `Copying to tmp table`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-profile.html "profiling is per process and not per thread. This means that activity on threads within the server other than your own may affect the timing information that you see."

Comment: @philipxy It's my dev-machine which is doing "nothing" in the background.

Comment: Well explained @PaulSpiegel. So what is the recommended way to use them ?

Comment: @prograshid I wouldn't care about the performance unless I can measure a significant difference. However - Since using an alias is not slower, I'd usualy us it. This also prevents code duplication. Consider if you have to change `count(*)` to `count(distinct id)` - Using alias you would need to change the code only in the SELECT clause.

Answer (score 0):

An Alias is just a synonym, so any timing differences are probably due to the phase of the moon.